# Prevent Kendo MultiSelect from expanding

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-multiselect

Kendo MultiSelect automatically expands after items exceeds its border
instead I want to prevent this behavior adding dumpy item with tool-tip containing the other items textFields.

Comment: You can use the single tag mode: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/multiselect/tag-mode

Comment: @ataravati I Forgot to mention I'm stuck with KendoUI 2013 , tag-mode is not there yet.